# How to add a custom object type in CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter

In codeigniter we have the standard classes of an mvc framework, models,views, libraries,etc. I'd like to add my own sub-set of objects to CodeIgniter, how can I best go about that? for example:

directories:

```
controllers
core
helpers
etc..
widgets //custom object type
```

inside of core, I could have a `My_Widget` class that everything in the widget folder would extend.  Then, inside of a controller I could have something like:

```
$this->load->widget('Example_Widget');
```

Comment: I have updated my answer.  I found a great example of someone implementing what you are attempting to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never done this so I can't offer you a complete solution, but I can at least try to point you in the right direction.

Take a look at the Loader Class, located in `/system/core/Loader.php`.  This is what you are accessing when you use `$this->load`.  It contains a number of methods for loading resources of different types (models, libraries, etc).  You may be able to get away with duplicating the `model()` method, renaming it `widget()`, and updating the paths to check an `/application/widgets` directory.  You might need to do a little more, such as creating a CI_Widget base class, but you should be able to go line by line through the method and figure out what it requires to work.

I hope this helps.

**Edit (1/12/2012):**

Here is an example of someone extending CodeIgniter to support a custom resource type.

[Sparks](http://getsparks.org/) is a package management system for CodeIgniter much like RubyGems for Ruby.  Using a spark is simple.  Once you have modified your CodeIgniter environment to support sparks, you simply install the spark and then load it using `$this->load->spark('...');`.  Modifying your CodeIgniter environment to support sparks simply entails extending the Loader Class to support the new `sparks()` method.

The code for modifying the Loader Class is available [here](http://getsparks.org/static/install/MY_Loader.php.txt).  Following the pattern in that file, you should be able implement loading of your own custom resource types.  In my previous answer I said that you could get away with modifying the `/system/core/Loader.php` file although I would recommend you follow the approach used by sparks and use a `/application/core/MY_Loader.php` file.

Comment: wow, I wish i could vote your answer up twice. one for a good answer and once for showing me sparks. That looks really handy.